# create unique combination of characters from same array in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a string array = String[] str = {"a","b","c","d"} that I want o multiply with itself thrice to get triplets in this form = {a,b,c}..and so on.

I wrote this code:

```
String[] str = {"a","b","c","d"};

    for(int i=0; i<str.length;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<str.length;j++){
            for(int k=2; k<str.length;k++){

                System.out.println(str[i]+"_"+str[j]+"_"+str[k]);

            }
        }
    }
```

But the output I get looks like this:

```
a_b_c
a_b_d
a_c_c
a_c_d
a_d_c
a_d_d
b_b_c
b_b_d
```

I want only unique combinations: a_b_c, a_b_d, a_c_d, b_c_d

Can I get some help here please?

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip repeated strings by using `continue` if you're processing elements that are equal.

```
String[] str = {"a","b","c","d"};

for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < str.length; j++) {
        if (str[j].equals(str[i]))
            continue;
        for (int k = 2; k < str.length; k++) {
            if (str[k].equals(str[i]) || str[k].equals(str[j]))
                continue;
            System.out.println(str[i] + "_" + str[j] + "_" + str[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you know that `str` does not contain duplicate elements (or if you want to include duplicates in that case), then you can skip based on equality of indices rather than elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < str.length; j++) {
        if (i == j)
            continue;
        for (int k = 2; k < str.length; k++) {
            if (i == k || j == k)
                continue;
            System.out.println(str[i] + "_" + str[j] + "_" + str[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!